# How old will Moshiach be when he is revealed

Tags: messiah

According to our sages of blessed memory Moshiach will be well immersed in the Torah, so how old then will Moshiach be when he is revealed.

As Maimonides states, "If there arises a ruler from the family of David, immersed in the Torah and its commandments like David his ancestor, following both the Written and Oral Torah, who leads Israel back to the Torah, strengthening the observance of its laws and fighting God's battles, then we may assume that he is the Messiah. If he is further successful in rebuilding the Temple on its original site and gathering the dispersed of Israel, then his identity as Messiah is a certainty."

Comment: Hi @arthurlerner, welcome to mi.yodeya! Akin to the comments on [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75766/3), can you provide a source for _mashiach_'s immersion in Torah? It will help clarify what type of information you are looking for.

Comment: I would think that the other items on Ramba"m's list of accomplishments would actually set the presumed age higher than the criterion of immersion in Torah, wouldn't you? Do you have reason to believe that the latter would take longer than the formers?

Comment: Shlomo HaMelech was 12 when he became king.

Comment: @Yishai And Shaul was 1.

Comment: The answer is no one knows http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28187/759

Comment: why is his age important?

Comment: @double, he was 30, as you well know. No need to speak in riddles.

Answer (score 1):

There is a teaching based upon [Micah 7:15](http://www.sefaria.org/Micah.7?lang=en) that much of the final redemption, including the revelation of Moshiach, will follow the same pattern as the first redemption from Egypt.

In the first redemption, Moshe Rabbeinu was 80 years old. So according to this tradition, you could expect something similar.

This is also in keeping with a parallel idea found in [Sefer Ohr HaChamah, Shemot 7b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21490&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=) which discusses when the Moshiach himself will know for a certainty that he is the Moshiach. It explains that this will take place later in his life. And as it explains there, even then, when Moshiach knows this about himself, many people in the world will still not know it about him.

According to what is taught by Rabbi Chaim Vital there, Moshiach will become aware that he is Moshiach at the time that he merits to prophecy. This, it states, is like Moshe Rabbeinu when he attained prophecy at the burning bush.

To emphasize, tradition teaches that the level of prophecy of Moshiach will rival, but not be as great as Moshe. Since part of the quantification of Moshe's level is how quickly he attained prophecy, it means Moshiach will attain this similar level at or slightly after the time Moshe did. Moshe achieved this when he was 80 years old.

Comment: `In the first redemption, Moshe Rabbeinu was 80 years old. So according to this tradition, you could expect something similar.` Should we also expect the Moshiach to be a shepherd or to have a Midianite wife? How far do you want to extend this comparison? || The *Or HaChama* doesn't indicate that `it will take place later in life`. It just says that the Moshiach will gradually develop until close to the time of "the end of days" when he will realize he is Moshiach. Although this process is compared to Moshe, there's no reason to think this will specifically happen "later in life."

Comment: @Fred Actually, the discussion of the 'lavat aish' is corresponding to Moshe's first contact with the burning bush. The chronological discussion in Ohr HaChamah is precise. You can choose to believe whatever you would like but the traditional teaching is there. Concerning the 'shepherd' concept, the leader of the generation is called the 'shepherd of faith' for their generation. So that would also apply.

Comment: Concerning the Midianite wife, since that option was precluded after the giving of the Torah, I would think not likely.

Comment: If you're going to interpret "shepherd" figuratively, you may as well interpret the age figuratively, too (e.g. wise beyond his years, or like R' El'azar ben 'Azarya, "*harei ani k'ven shiv'im shana*"), as opposed to saying the Moshiach has to be exactly 80 years old. Or just follow the Rambam's advice instead (*Hil. M'lachim* 12:2): "וכל אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן **לא ידע אדם איך יהיו עד שיהיו** שדברים סתומין הן אצל הנביאים גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו אלא לפי הכרע הפסוקים ולפיכך יש להם מחלוקת בדברים אלו... ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות ולא יאריך במדרשות האמורים בענינים אלו וכיוצא בהן".

Comment: Like I said before, you can choose to believe whatever you like. But the sources exist as presented. Your understanding of that halacha from Rambam is incorrect. He isn't disqualifying anything in Torah. He is discussing the subject of the specific order of certain events, namely the natural period and miraculous period of the redemption, the war of Gog and the coming of Eliyahu via resurrection. He doesn't say they won't happen. He just says what order those things unfold won't be known for certain until they actually happen.

Comment: `Your understanding of that halacha from Rambam is incorrect. He isn't disqualifying anything in Torah.` I didn't say he was, and I'm not disputing that the future redemption will parallel *y'tzi'as Mitzrayim*. My dispute is that you say the moshiach will be "similar" to 80 years old (by the way: if you're insisting that he'll be Moshe's age, why not exactly 80?), whereas I'm saying that the degree and manner in which the redemption will parallel *y'tzi'as Mitzrayim* is not specified when it comes to the moshiach's age. And people can read *Or HaChama* themselves to see what it says.

Comment: The subject discussed in Ohr HaChamah is talking about Moshiach's spiritual growth from his birth forward. You could make the argument that he will surpass Moshe, meaning he would be younger. But there are numerous sources which discuss this and say he will approach the level of Moshe, not surpass it. That implies being about the same age or possibly a little older.

Comment: `You could make the argument that he will surpass Moshe...` That's not my argument (though the only area where it's generally accepted that Moshe will surpass everyone — including the moshiach — is that Moshe's level of prophecy is qualitatively superior). Just because someone develops spiritually at a younger age does not mean they are superior. | `or possibly a little older` So you're saying the moshiach may be older than 80? But if you're insisting that the verse from Micha indicates a parallel in age, you're contradicting yourself by saying it doesn't have to be *quite* parallel after all.

Comment: You don't understand the meaning of the word 'parallel'. And no, I am not contradicting anything.

Comment: From Merriam-Webster's Dictionary: Parallel: very similar and often happening at the same time.

Comment: Regardless of the semantics of the word "parallel" in English, you're arbitrarily deciding the parameters of the degree and manner in which the final redemption will resemble the redemption from Egypt: "Yes, that means the Moshiach will be the same age as Moshe was. But not exactly, just plus a few years." And if you think this is what the *Or HaChama* is saying, you're really stretching the meaning of the *Or HaChama*.

Comment: Actually the concept of paralleling is understood from the Micah quoted. The letter 'Kaf' in 'like the days' (כימי) means similar or parallel. And from your comments it also sounds like you don't understand the text cited in Ohr HaChamah. Once again, you can believe whatever you choose, but the sources cited stand. It's no 'stretch'.

Comment: `Actually the concept of paralleling is understood from the Micah quoted.` But your application of the concept is not (though obviously you disagree). And I'm quite well aware of this concept and its source from Micha. We seem to be going in circles, so let's leave it at that. Kol tuv.

Answer (score -4):

I believe that Moshiach will be around seventy.  David told us that our years would be seventy, maybe eighty if we are lucky. This leads me to believe that he will be close to this age.

Comment: That wasn't David. It was Moses.

Comment: And what makes you think Moshiach will be near the end of his natural life?